# Puppeteer in docker container: Chromium revision is not downloaded

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, puppeteer

I'm trying to launch puppeteer in an express app that's run in a docker container, using docker-compose.

The line that should launch puppeteer `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});` throws the following error:

`(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install"`

I've tried adding a `yarn add puppeteer` after the `yarn install` and also replacing `yarn install` in the `Dockerfile` with `npm install` .

What needs to change, so that I can use puppeteer with chromium as expected?

#### Express app's Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8

RUN apt-get update

# for https
RUN apt-get install -yyq ca-certificates
# install libraries
RUN apt-get install -yyq libappindicator1 libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6
# tools
RUN apt-get install -yyq gconf-service lsb-release wget xdg-utils
# and fonts
RUN apt-get install -yyq fonts-liberation

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY code/package.json /usr/src/app
COPY code/index.js /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/views
COPY code/views/ /usr/src/app

# install the necessary packages
RUN yarn install

CMD npm run start:dev
```

#### docker-compose.yml:

```
app:
    restart: always
    build: ${REPO}
    volumes:
        - ${REPO}/code:/usr/src/app:ro
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
        - "8087:5000"
```

#### index.js route:

```
app.post('/img', function (req, res) {
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  (async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
  })();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem and I wanted to leave the simple solution. The reason it couldn't find my chrome install is that I had mounted my local volume into the container for testing. I use a mac, so the local `npm install` gave me the mac version of chromium. When that `node_modules` folder was mounted into the linux container, it expected to find the linux version which was not there.

To get around this, you need to exclude your `node_modules` folder when you're doing a volume mount into the container. I was able to do that by passing another `volume` parameter.

```
docker run -rm \
  --volume ~/$project:/dist/$project \
  --volume /dist/$project/node_modules
```

Comment: Great overlooked point. Might using a .dockerignore -> node_modules be another way to prevent the the local version of chromium from crossing over into the container?

Answer (score 8):

The docker volume I was using mapped the entire local `code` directory to the docker container's `/usr/src/app` directory.

This is great for allowing quick code updates during development.

However, it also overwrites the version of chromium previously installed on the **docker container** via the `yarn install` in the `Dockerfile` with the version of chromium installed on **my machine** via `yarn install` in the command line.

Each machine needs its own, correct, os-specific version of chromium.  The docker container needs a linux-specific chromium (`linux-515411`), my laptop needs a mac-specific chromium (`mac-508693`).  Simply running `yarn install` (or `npm install`) with puppeteer in your `package.json` will handle installing the correct version of chromium.

#### Previous project structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
└── code
    ├── index.js
    ├── package.json
    └── node_modules
        ├── lots of other node packages
        └── puppeteer
            ├── .local-chromium
            │     └── mac-508693 <--------good for macs, bad for linux!
            ├── package.json
            └── all the other puppeteer files
```

#### Partial Dockerfile

This is where the container gets its own version of `.local-chromium`:

```
FROM node:8

RUN apt-get update

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY code/package.json /usr/src/app
COPY code/index.js /usr/src/app

# install the necessary packages <------ including puppeteer, with the correct chromium
RUN yarn install

CMD npm run start:dev
```

#### Previous volumes from `docker-compose.yml`

This copies everything from the local `${REPO}/code` to the docker container's `/usr/src/app` directory. **Including the wrong version of chromium.**

```
volumes:
    - ${REPO}/code:/usr/src/app:ro
```

#### Updated project structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
└── code
    ├── src
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── package.json
    └── node_modules
        ├── lots of other node packages
        └── puppeteer
            ├── .local-chromium
            ├── package.json
            └── all the other puppeteer files
```

Updated docker volume maps the entire contents of the local `./code/src` to the docker container's `/usr/src/app`. This does *NOT* include the `node_modules` directory:

```
volumes:
    - ${REPO}/code/src:/usr/src/app:ro
```

Comment: Could you please explain more your solution? I'm having the same issue but I'm not sure of what to do. I'm not using docker compose yet, still I'm facing the same problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @jprivillaso Take a look at the edited/rewritten answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys please visit this link. This is quite helpful for you who want to launch headless puppeter inside docker container

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

This is my project code structure

- config
- migrations
- models
- utils
- .dockerignorefile
- app.js
- **docker-compose.yml**
- **Dockerfile**
- package.json

Make sure you have install docker. Once installed you can follow these procedure

*Run **docker-compose up --build** inside your docker directory*

And [this](https://github.com/frayhan94/mandiri-scrap) is my repo regarding headless chrome inside docker